# cordovaCamera image not binding in html

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

So, i am using the cordovaCamera plugin to take a photo and then show that photo in my html view but weirdly the image doesnt bind to the view and i am very confused as to wht i am doing wrong. Here is my code

```
$scope.takePhoto = function(index) {
    var options = {
      destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit : false,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      correctOrientation: true
    };

   // 3
    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
   // 4
    var imagetype;
      onImageSuccess(imageData);

      function onImageSuccess(fileURI) {
        createFileEntry(fileURI);
      }

      function createFileEntry(fileURI) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURI, copyFile, fail);
      }

     // 5
      function copyFile(fileEntry) {
        var name = fileEntry.fullPath.substr(fileEntry.fullPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        var newName = (new Date()).getTime() + name;
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(fileSystem2) {
          fileEntry.copyTo(
            fileSystem2,
            newName,
            onCopySuccess,
            fail
          );
        }, fail);
      }

       // 6
      function onCopySuccess(entry) {
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/profile_picture.html', {
          scope: $scope,
          animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function(modal) {
          $scope.modal = modal;
          $scope.modal.show();
          $scope.myCroppedImage = entry.nativeURL;
        });

        $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
          $scope.modal.remove();
        });
      }

      function fail(error) {
      }
    }, function(err) {
    });
  };
```

profile_picture.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Profile Picture" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <ion-nav-bar class="menu-background" nav-view-direction="none" nav-view-transition="" hide-nav-bar="false">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-android-arrow-back" menu-toggle="left" ng-click="cancelCropModal()"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
            <div>
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-android-done" ng-click="closeCropModal()"></button>
            </div>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-content>
    <div class="cropArea">
      <img-crop image="myImage" result-image="myCroppedImage"></img-crop>
            <img id="croppedImage" ng-src="{{myCroppedImage}}" alt="" />
    </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

But what happens is once the image is captured, it doesnt bind to the view and the page is empty. Why doesnt it bind and what could be the reason?

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: can you try ng-src="myCroppedImage"

Comment: ng-src="myCroppedImage" or ng-src="{{myCroppedImage}}"?

Comment: @PareshGami doesnt work. still empty.

Comment: entry.nativeURL is display url in console?

Comment: what is they display?